# How do I measure my site's bandwidth?

Tags: server, bandwidth

A newbie question, but I have a PHP site running on dedicated Centos server with plesk control panel and wonder how much bandwidth is being consumed. Is there a tool or code that measures bandwidth per month, per day etc?

Answer (score 2):

Plesk already has a "Statistics" area which includes that information, among other things. Is there a reason you're not just using it?

(Or is it that you want something additional for comparison or whatever?)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like [vnStat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/). It works at the level of the network stack's own traffic counters and is therefore "light" on monitoring overhead.